# How to set the right CocoaPods source

Tags: git, github, cocoapods

I'm trying to create my first CocoaPods dependency but having some problems with the source.

Here's my [Github Repo](https://github.com/yoeriboven/TopAlignedCollectionViewLayout). What URL should I set as the source so the folder `YBTopAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout` is the source folder? It seems like I can only set the complete repo as the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on what @orbey said you do have to take all or nothing of the source. Although you can easily write your podspec so that it sources the files from that directory so it shouldn't really matter. Look at some of the existing specs in the repo for examples, practically all of then have to do that.

Comment: Turned out I could set `s.source_files` and set a path. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check out a repository's subdirectory in Git as a new repository - it's all or nothing.

Is there some reason you can't create a new branch in your existing working copy to create this dependency? Changes in branches will stay isolated until you choose to merge them back in to the master branch.